# Endpoints cost on Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-machine-learning-service

I have been following the learning path for [Microsoft Azure AI 900](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/certifications/exams/ai-900). In the second module, I have deployed my model as an endpoint. It says Container instances for compute type. How much will this cost me. Azure doesn't seem to show any pricing for this. Is this endpoint always active? If yes how much does it cost?

Comment: There is a [Container Instances princing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/container-instances/) where you can get an estimate of how much a container instance will cost. You pay for memory, cpu and gpu time, and also for windows license time for windows containers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The price depends on the number of **vCPU** and **GBs** of memory requested for the container group. You are charged based on the **vCPU request** for your container group rounded up to the nearest whole number for the duration (measured in seconds) **your instance is running**. You are also charged for the **GB request** for your container group rounded up to the nearest tenths place for the duration (measured in seconds) your **container group is running**. There is an additional charge of $0.000012 per vCPU second for Windows software duration on Windows container groups. Check here [Pricing - Container Instances | Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/container-instances/) for details

- After Deployed the Azure Machine Learning managed online endpoint (preview).
- Have at least [Billing Reader](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal.md) access on the subscription where the endpoint is deployed

To know the costs estimation

1. In the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/), Go to your subscription
2. Select **Cost Analysis** for your subscription.

[image]

Create a filter to scope data to your Azure Machine learning workspace resource:

1. At the top navigation bar, select **Add filter**.
2. In the first filter dropdown, select **Resource** for the filter type.
3. In the second filter dropdown, select your Azure Machine Learning workspace.

[image]

Create a tag filter to show your managed online endpoint and/or managed online deployment:

1. Select **Add filter** > **Tag** > **azuremlendpoint**: "< your endpoint name>"
2. Select **Add filter** > **Tag** > **azuremldeployment**: "< your deployment name>".

[image]

Refer  [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/machine-learning/how-to-view-online-endpoints-costs.md)  for more detailed steps